# sharing mutexes between modules

Tags: c, mutex

How does one use mutexes between modules?

I have a module that creates threads that run functions from another module.

I need to read a variable in the thread creating module and the threads that execute functions from other #included modules modify the variable. How does locking and unlocking of the mutexes occur in a system like this?

e.g. Logic module spawns 2 threads, each run a function from another module. There is a variable called current position that needs to be read from the logic module if e.g. another module calls getCurrentPosition. How do these threaded functions that are existing outside of the logic module use the mutexes defined in the logic module?

The thread running functions need to lock and unlock the mutex that is defined in the logic module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use mutex just like you declare and use extern variable "current position". No big difference here.

```
extern pthread_mutex_t mtx;
extern int current_position;
```

Answer (score 1):

Mutex is is usually used with a pointer to mutex object. So, you must pass the pointer to same object into both modules and then you can use mutex as usual.

You can add `extern mutex_type mutex1;` declaration of mutex pointer into header file common to both modules but define it in one module with `mutex_type mutex1;`. Then you can use `&mutex1` in both modules.